# Convert an Serverdate in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, date

Startdate: 2014-05-14T00:00:00.000+02:00
[PDF Output]

I use an .tmpl (Html Build), with following function:

```
    <div class="txt"><tr><td style="width: 131px">Startdate:                </td> 
                        <td style="width: 473px">   {{STARTDATE}}</td></tr></div><br>
    <div class="txt"><tr><td style="width: 131px">Enddate:              </td> 
                        <td style="width: 473px">   {{ENDDATE}}</td></tr></div><br>
```

The {{ FUNCTION }} open the Function and use the server date.

How can i convert the {{STARTDATE}} to an yyyy.mm.dd or dd.mm.yyyy ?

Not with the "T00:00:00.000+02:00"

Comment: Had to be done in server side. Between, which template language and which backend technology are you using?

Comment: no, its work on Javascript, in my webclient the date has yyyy.mm.dd, its only in the PDF export..

Comment: There are so many javascript libraries available which gives different function to perform on js date object.You can use any or just make a js function which satisfy your need.

Comment: Recommendation: sugar.js for datetime support.